# crear directorios desde python

Tags: python

Amigos estoy desarrollando un codigo que almacena fotos pero tengo un error en la creacion de las carpetas donde almacenara las fotos espero me puedan ayudar tengo este codigo:

```
curDir = os.getcwd()

if key == ord("k"):
    p = os.path.sep.join([curDir, "dataset", os.mkdir(name), "{}.png".format(
        str(total).zfill(5))])
    cv2.imwrite(p, orig)
    total += 1
```

les esplico el codigo si aprimo la 'k' toma la foto y curDir captura la direccion de las carpetas, dataset asi se llama la carpeta donde quiero almacenar las fotos tomadas, lo siguiente es que me cree una carpta con el nombre que ya anteriormente la asigne y que se almacene en la variable name y por ultimo le pongo .png y le pongo un contador para nombrar las fotos tomadas y me sale el siguite error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "face_video.py", line 69, in <module>
    str(total).zfill(5))])
TypeError: sequence item 2: expected str instance, NoneType found
```

espero me ayuden a despejar la duda..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error lo que te está diciendo es que [`join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) está esperando una cadena, en el tercer valor de la lista (índice 2), sin embargo el valor que tenemos es un `None`. El problema es que `os.mkdir(name)` no retorna ningún valor. La solución sería crear la carpeta por afuera de la definición de la lista y usar solamente el nombre:

```
os.mkdir(name)
p = os.path.sep.join([curDir, "dataset", name, "{}.png".format(
        str(total).zfill(5))])
```

O bien envolver `os.mkdir` en una función propia que retorne el nombre de la carpeta:

```
def mkdir_with_return(name):
  os.mkdir(name)
  return name
```

Answer (score 1):

Revisa esta parte

```
 p = os.path.sep.join([curDir, "dataset", os.mkdir(name), "{}.png".format(
        str(total).zfill(5))])
```

Específicamente `str(total).zfill(5)`

Puede ser que el método `join` no acepte ese tipo de dato.

total = str(total.zfill(5))

Comment: ok te entiendo la respuesta @fernando carraro pero mira si le quito el parametro os.mkdir(name) que es el que me crea la carpeta con el nombre de la variable almacenada en name si funciona poniendo el codigo asi: if key == ord("k"):
  p = os.path.sep.join([curDir, "dataset", "{}.png".format(
   str(total).zfill(5))])
  cv2.imwrite(p, orig)
  total += 1